# Why does ode45 not return solutions at the time points I request, even though I specify a timespan with more than 2 elements?

Tags: matlab

My matlab script is very simple:

```
tstart = 0;
tend = 10;
num_points = 50;
ts = linspace(tstart, tend, num_points);

x_0 = rand(2, 1); % random column vector

kmat = rand(2, 2); % random RHS matrix

sol = ode45(@(t, x) F(x, kmat), ts', x_0);

xs = sol.y;
size(xs)
```

Where the function `F` is defined in `F.m` as:

```
function result = F(x, kmat)
    result = kmat*x;
end
```

Now, when I run this script, I get the following output (the size of `xs`):

```
size_xs =

     2    12
```

However, I clearly specified that I wanted the ODE to be solved on 50 points in between 0 and 10 (see `linspace` command defining `ts`). If I try and find the size of `ts` I get:

```
>> size(ts)

ans =

     1    50
```

So there are 50 points in `ts`, but `ode45` is ignoring this? How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [single output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?expandAllPage=true#f92-1000853) form will always return a structure for use with [`deval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html) to generate dense output.

To automatically return the points you requested through the time vector (`ts` in this case), you need to use the [two-output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?expandAllPage=true#f92-1027258) form:

```
[t,xs] = ode45(@(t, x) F(x, kmat), ts', x_0);
```